# angular-ui-router:Unable to load child state page in view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I am using angular UI-Router. I want to show user search page in parent state and user information in child state.

**app.js**

```
.state('users', {
        url: "/users",
        templateUrl: "app/views/user/userSearchPage.html",
        controller: "userCtrl"
    })
      .state('users.edit', {
          url: "/:username/edit",
          templateUrl: "app/views/user/tenantUser.html",
          controller: "userCtrl"
      })
```

When I try to load child state view it still shows parent state view.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a child state, it's supposed that parent state is not exited on entering child. Thus, the reason you don't see anything is that template `app/views/user/userSearchPage.html` is missing a `<ui-view></ui-view>` in markup. Because `edit` is defined as a nested state, templates should be nested too. The only way to nest in ui-router is to define a ui-view to give a placeholder for child template.

Beware of double instances of controllers. If template contains `ng-controller="userCtrl"` there will be two instances created, one by template another by router

If you'd like templates to force each other out you shouldn't define states nested. They are sibling states by nature

```
.state('users', {
    url: "/users",
    templateUrl: "app/views/user/userSearchPage.html",
    controller: "userCtrl"
})    
.state('edit', {
    url: "/edit/:username",
    templateUrl: "app/views/user/tenantUser.html",
    controller: "userCtrl"
})
```

With updated info from comments I can propose three ways to solve scenario, search, find results, edit one item (full screen template), go back to search and see data.

1. The simple way would be to add the search parameters to state and its url and be able to return to it. In this case angular will reload search page again. It is possible to do if you follow REST pattern in your architecture, i.e. same query params always define same data.
2. More complicated and saving search data while editing an item would be to use [sticky states](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/sticky/#/) from ui-router-extras. You will have to define a named ui-view for search and for edit. `users` and `edit` should become sibling (as I proposed above) and get `sticky: true` and templates should be defined for named ui-views.

   .state('users', {
       url: "/users",
       sticky: true,
       views:{
         search: {
            templateUrl: "app/views/user/userSearchPage.html",
            controller: "userCtrl"
          }
       } 
   })
   .state('edit', {
       url: "/edit/:username",
       sticky: true,
       views:{
         search: {
           templateUrl: "app/views/user/tenantUser.html",
           controller: "userCtrl"
          }
       } 
   })

In container template you define two ui-views instead of one

```
<ui-view name="search"></ui-view>
<ui-view name="edit"></ui-view>
```

3. Possible but crude. I don't like this approach because it won't scale well.
   States are child as you have originally. Search template should be changed

> ```
> <div ng-show="$state.current.name.indexOf('.edit') >= 0">
>   all your existing markup for search here 
> </div>
>
>  child template will be nested here when appropriate state is set
>  but as the above part will hide it, will imitate replacing template
> <ui-view></ui-view>
> ```

Comment: yes but I want to show only `app/views/user/tenantUser.html` template when I am in child state. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you change child state to a sibling state?

Comment: Child state will inherit parent state also but i don't want to do it. When search result is there I will click on particular record and I will show user information when I back to search page I have to show same search result.

Comment: First there is no trouble to remember previous state and return there. The simple way would be to add the search parameter to state and its url and be able to return to it. More complicated and saving search data while editing an item would be to use [sticky states](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/sticky/#/) from ui-router-extras

Comment: Yes I know but here we are not updating search parameters in state and if I add also it needs to update 6 parameters in state. My requirement is to with out changing state params I have to show search result. When i go to user info page and on came back I have to show search result. Is it possible? Could you please suggest any better approach?

Comment: Mentioned sticky states only. Take a look at the demo. Your search page will just hide, when you're back from edit it's again displayed with all data previously found